# How can i get sum of all the numbers that this program prints?

Tags: python

```
B = 1
A = 3
C = 1
while C < 1000:
 B = B + 1
 C = A * B
 print (C)
```

This is the code and i want to get the sum of the numbers that it prints

Comment: `A + B + C` ? Why do you introduce a `while` ? Please, explain what you want to do ?

Comment: you have to append C var to list in a loop

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility,

```
B = 1
A = 3
C = 1
D = 0
while C < 1000:
 B = B + 1
 C = A * B
 D += C
 print (C)
# sum of all printed numbers
print(D)
```

Comment: OP wants to get the sum of the number that gets printed

Comment: D will be the sum of all printed numbers, since C is the only variable that's getting printed.

Comment: You are providing a cumsum and he have to save the last printed value of D to get the sum...so why not create a new list and append C to it and finally sum it.

Comment: It's mentioned nowhere that OP needs to retain the list of printed numbers, so why waste memory by saving numbers in a list? In addition to that, `sum(list)` loops over the contents of list and produces a sum, my answer does exactly that minus the overhead of saving to a list and doing a sum.

Comment: @sixd, your solution is correct and it is faster than adding to a list ;).

Answer (score 1):

`B` runs over all the integers from `2` to `334`; you only need the sum of all integers from `2` to `334` (which is well known: average * number of elements) and then multiply it by `A`:

```
A = 3
B_max = 334  # ~ (1000 // A) + ...
res = A * (B_max + 2) * (B_max - 1) // 2
# 167832
```

you just need to make sure you get `B_max` right...

there is no reason for a loop at all if that is all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

define a list outside while:

```
dataList = []
```

then add C in that list:

```
while C < 1000:
    B = B + 1
    C = A * B
    dataList.append(C)
```

then find sum:

```
print(sum(dataList))
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, your goal is not clear. can you explain it more for me to be able to help you?

PS. your B = B + 1 can be simplified to:

> B += 1

Answer (score 0):

You should declare SUM first:

SUM=0

And at the end of while loop after print message, add

SUM = SUM + C

And thats all, simplest possible way.

Answer (score 0):

```
B = 1
A = 3
C = 1
total = 0
while C < 1000:
    B = B + 1
    C = A * B
    print(C)
    total+=C
print("Sum is : ",total)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.